# What is the number of relations on a set with n elements that are not antisymmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

My attempt
$A=\{1,2\}$
$$A×A={(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)}$$
The total antisymmetric relations on $A×A$ is $12$
And remaining 4 are not antisymmetric.
Is it mean if on a particular set if some relations are antisymmetric then the remaining would be not antisymmetric?
A set with 3 elements have 216 antisymmetric relations.is it mean the remaining 296 are not antisymmetric?
Antisymmetric relations can also be find from
$$2^n \times 3 ^{n(n-2)\over 2}$$

Comment: How did you find antisymmetric relations to be 64?

Comment: Apparently by being half asleep: that was the last thing that I did last night. Your figure is correct. And yes, it means that the remaining $296$ are not antisymmetric.